# Symfony2 - Catchable Fatal Error: _construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, entitymanager, event-listener

I am building the 'Last Logged In' feature. After creating the activitylistener and defining the listener as a service, I get an error

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Acme\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\sinfoc\public\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 350 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\sinfoc\public\src\Acme\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener.php line 22

Here is my ActivityListener Class

```
 public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, EntityManager $entityManager)
        {
            $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
            $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        }
```

And here is the services.yml where the listener is defined as a service

```
services:
    activity_listener:
        class: Bnpp\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener
        arguments: [@security.context, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onCoreController }
```

Here is the complete ActivityListenerClass

```
 <?php

namespace Bnpp\SecurityBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
//use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Bnpp\SecurityBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;


/**
 * Listener that updates the last activity of the authenticated user
 */

class ActivityListener

    {
    protected $securityContext;
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }



    /**
     * Update the user "lastActivity" on each request
     * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
     */


    public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {

        // Check that the current request is a "MASTER_REQUEST"
        // Ignore any sub-request
        if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            return;
        }

        // Check token authentication availability
        if ($this->securityContext->getToken()) {
            $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();


            if ( ($user instanceof User) && !($user->isActiveNow()) ) {
                $user->setLastActivity(new \DateTime('now'));
                $this->entityManager->flush($user);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you not miss a part of error message ? Can you show the class declaration in ActivityListener.php ?

Comment: In continuation to what Patt suggested, I am not using the FOSUserBundle. I get this error while injecting @doctrine.orm.entity_manager

Comment: @PéCé Just added the whole error message and complete class declaration

Comment: Refresh your cache, it looks like ActivityListener receives '@doctrine' instead of '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' as 2nd parameter

Comment: @PéCé Cleared the cache. But the error persists.

Comment: Try with `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager`. As a side question - What version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: @Touki I tried doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager but no luck. I'm on Symfony 2.3

Comment: @CloudJedi, can you remove the folder app/cache completely and try again, see what you get.

Comment: @CloudJedi can you also make sure you have declared the service only once?

Comment: Did you find the solution at last?! because I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

From this error

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Acme\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\sinfoc\public\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 350 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\sinfoc\public\src\Acme\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener.php line 22

you are to provide

> Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,

but you provided

> Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry

at

```
 arguments: [@security.context, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

your argument should be

```
arguments:
         - "@security.context"
         - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```